# Google chrome blocking a simple link in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-chrome

I'm using the

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.website.com),"_Self");
}
```

to navigate to a URL when a button is clicked. Now for some reason the Google Chrome browser seems to be blocking the link from opening as it considers it as a "pop-up", even though it's set to open in the same tab (`_self`).

There must be a way round this right? I already know i can add it to my exceptions but I'm working on an online project that many people will be using. I don't want them have any silly issues like this.

I find it funny how NO browser will ever block the ACTUAL unwanted pop-ups but many of them will block the wanted pop-ups.

any help would be much appreciated.

cheers

Comment: Have you checked the values of the allowScriptAccess and allowNetworking parameters? For example if allowScriptAccess is not defined or set to none, navigateToUrl doesn't work with _self.

Comment: You forgot a single quote at the end of your URL, and as Jevgenij mentioned, you should use _self i.s.o _Self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please youse the default target names:

- "_blank"
- "_parent"
- "_self"
- "_top"

I think they are case sensitive.

in your case:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.website.com'),"_self");
```

works for me with `_self`, with `_Self` also taking as a popup.